# What algorithm can compute the edit distance between two strings with arbitrary insert, delete, replace and swap costs?

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I want to compute the edit distance between two strings, using 4 operations: character insertion, deletion, replacement and swapping. Each operation is associated with a cost. For instance, if the first three costs are equal to 10 and the last is equal to 1, we have:

distance(abc,bca) = 2 (swap a and b then swap a and c)

distance(abc,bae) = 11 (swap b and a then replace c by e)

distance(abcd,bdca) = 4

I read the [Wikipedia article about Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), but the algorithm they give works only if 2 × swapping cost ≥ insert cost + delete cost.

Comment: i don't think your function is well defined ...  if weighted-levenshtein is defined as the minimum-cost sequence of edits to transform the strings, then for your example 2, it should be cost 4 (i.e. 2 deletes + 2 inserts); more generally the significance of the inequality 
"2 × swapping cost ≥ insert cost + delete cost" is that if it's not satisfied you will always just delete and insert rather than swapping to get a lower score. does this make sense?

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense to swap several times rather than just inserting and deleting ? I do not see the problem in the definition. In my case, I want to favor having the same elements, even if they are far one to another, over having to insert completely new elements.

Comment: ah sorry misread your question, i think this is a (NP) hard problem, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292202/finding-the-minimum-number-of-swaps-to-convert-one-string-to-another-where-the