# Minimum swap sequence to make one array match another?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph-theory, swap

I have two arrays `A` and `B` of the same length.

`A` and `B` contain the same elements but in different order.

I need to make `A` match `B` *by only swapping any two elements within `A`*. I also need to do this **in the minimum number of swaps possible**. The array(s) can contain duplicate elements.

For example if

A = { 3, 8, 5, 8 }

B = { 8, 8, 3, 5 }

The minimum needed swaps is `2` and the sequence would be

```
swap(0, 2)
swap(0, 3)
```

I know how to find how many swaps are needed from sources like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7IIW0HVUcQ), [or here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-swaps-to-make-two-array-identical/) but I cannot find any information on **generating the sequence of swaps** needed to make `A` match `B`. I believe the solution involves directed graphs and cycles but I can't quite figure out a working algorithm that is less than O(n^2) time.

Comment: You can modify [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/): for each cycle store indexes and generate swaps for them. Cycle: 0->2->4->6->0 gives swaps: (0,2), (2,4), (4,6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the minimum number of swaps to convert one string to another, where the strings may have repeated characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292202/finding-the-minimum-number-of-swaps-to-convert-one-string-to-another-where-the)